# How can I delete everything after the first space Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I have a text looking like this

```
name_123 name 2022-6-1 abc
```

I want this

```
name_123
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to do this across a large number of values? A list?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the replace dialog
- Find what:  `.*`
- Replace with: empty
- Search mode: regular expression, with `. matches newline` **not** checked
- Replace All

`.*` means searching for a space ( ) followed by any characters (`.*`). Regex matches greedily by default so it'll match everything from the first space until the end of line

See also

- [Notepad++ delete everything in line after certain character?](https://superuser.com/q/1031841/241386)
- [Notepad++ How to cut all text after a specfic character](https://superuser.com/q/637992/241386)
- [How can I delete everything after the first column in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/q/800136/241386)

Answer (score 0):

You can also target the first word instead with: `^([^\s]*)\s.*$`
and replace with: `\1`.